# How do i select an array range where array index is greater than a certain value C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to select 15 events with each iteration of `i`.

In the first loop of `i`, I want to add `validbatch[0 to 15]`.

Next loop `validbatch[15 to 30]` and so on.

How do I filter or select a subarray from valid batch where the `index > i*15`?

```
for (j = counter; j < i * 15; j++)
{
    crm x = new crm();
    x.EmailAddress = EMAILaddress[j];
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.new_insideroptout = optin[j];
    validBatch[j] = new SampleEventBody() { Id = Int64.Parse(ID[j]), Publication = subscriptionname[j], CrmProperties = x, Properties = prop };
    counter++;
}
sendTasks.Add(client.SendEventBatchAsync(validBatch.Where<EventBody>(validbatch => validBatch[j] > validbatch[i * 15 - 1])
```

Comment: You need to add more information as this is hard to understand. try to be more explicit with your intended outcome

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following generic method to split an array.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitArray<T>(this T[] array, int size)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < (float)array.Length / size; i++)
    {
        yield return array.Skip(i * size).Take(size);
    }
}
```

And then you can call it like

```
var splitedArray = array.SplitArray(2);
```

I hope you are looking for this.